# Golang - How to create callback notification

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a case where a client sends a POST request to subscribe to some service to a server.

The server has to respond with the subscription data, however after some time if there is a change in the subscription information in the server, the server has to send a notification to the client about the changes using the "nfStatusNotificationUri" in the request body ("nfStatusNotificationUri" in the JSON 
data below).

I do not know how to do this.

I have implemented the POST subscription part but have no idea how to implement the notification part.

Can anyone help me or give me some guidance on`enter code here` how to do this.

This what I have done so far:

// server
// functions

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) Insertsub(nfinstancesub Subscriptions) error {
    err := db.C(COLLECTION).Insert(&nfinstancesub)
    return err
}

func CreateNewSubscriptionPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var nfinstancesub Subscriptions
    id := uuid.New()
    subscriptionID := id.String()

    if r.Header.Get("Accept") != "application/json" {
        WriteError(w, ErrNotAcceptable)
        return
    }
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&nfinstancesub); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid request payload")
        return
    }
    nfinstancesub.ID = bson.NewObjectId()
    nfinstancesub.SubscriptionID = subscriptionID
    if err := da.Insertsub(nfinstancesub); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Response-Code", "201")
    w.Header().Set("Response-Desc", "Success")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=2592000") // 30 days
    respondWithJson(w, http.StatusCreated, nfinstancesub)
}
```

// Main function

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/nnrf-nfm/v1/subscriptions, CreateNewSubscriptionPost)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The JSON data to request subscription including the notification uri "nfStatusNotificationUri" field.
Am using mongodb to store this JSON data request is sent.

```
{
  "nfStatusNotificationUri": "string",
  "subscriptionID": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "validityTime": "2019-02-11T09:45:52.015Z",
  "reqNotifEvents": [
    "NF_REGISTERED",
    "string"
  ],
  "plmnId": {
    "mcc": "string",
    "mnc": "string"
  },
  "notifCondition": {
    "monitoredAttributes": [
      "string"
    ],
    "unmonitoredAttributes": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "reqNfFqdn": "string"
}
```

Comment: I've voted for closing this question mainly because there are several ways to achieve what you want to do. I highly recommend you to read something about pub/sub system

Comment: Your question is too broad for a simple answer. As @Tinwor mentioned above you might want to take a look at the pubsubhub protocol which is designed for this exact purpose. Your code as is is just a simple web service over http and you're likely to hit a dead end trying to find a solution this way.